# Convertir formato dd/MM/yy a dd/MM/yyyy, no funciona

Tags: java, localdate, date-format

Uso el siguiente código para recibir una fecha:

```
DateTimeFormatter formato;
formato = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yy");
LocalDate fecha = LocalDate.parse(19/07/63, formato);
```

la cuál debería parsearse como `19/07/1963`, pero al realizar ese formato y ver que dato de fecha me queda, me sale `19/07/2063`, investigue un poco pero no hay mucha información al respecto, podrían orientarme?

Comment: Hola, Harold. De casualidad, ¿es esto lo que necesitas? [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38354151/how-to-force-java-time-localdate-to-assume-19th-century-as-yy-year-pattern ]

Comment: Sí, es lo que necesito, pero al ejecutarlo, me da este error. Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '13/01/63' could not be parsed at index 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para los que usen LocalDate y DateTimeFormatter, este es el código que me soluciono mi problema.

```
DateTimeFormatter formato;
formato = DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("dd/MM/")
                .optionalStart()
                .appendPattern("yyyy")
                .optionalEnd()
                .optionalStart()
                .appendValueReduced(ChronoField.YEAR_OF_ERA, 2, 2, 1900)
                .optionalEnd()
                .toFormatter();
LocalDate fecha = LocalDate.parse(19/07/63, formato);
```

Para obtener como salida

```
19/07/1963
```

Answer (score 2):

Se debe a que no estas definiendo en realidad un formato de salida, en este caso deberìa ser "dd/MM/yyyy" para que obtengas `19/07/1963`.

```
       //Formato inicial.
       String inputFormat = "dd/MM/yy";
       //Formato deseado.
       String outputFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
          
       String inputDate = "19/07/63";
       
   String outputDate = inputDate;
   try {
        outputDate = new SimpleDateFormat(outputFormat).format(new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat).parse(inputDate));
   } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("formateDateFromstring(): " + e.getMessage());
            outputDate = "";
   }
 
       System.out.println(outputDate);
```

Tendrìas como salida:

```
19/07/1963
```